# Read from file up to another point C++

Tags: c++, file, input, io

So I have a list

> {"ID":"55e5f0c8ace3e","nombre":"Jacqueline ","apellido":"Charlet ","sobrenombre":"","edad":"30","caracteristicas":"","comentario":"",

I need to change that list and put it in a correct way like:
ID: 55e5f0c8ace3e
Nombre: Jacqueline
Apellido: ...
etc..

Tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream datos("datos.txt");
ofstream final("final.txt");

int main(){
    char valor;
    if(!datos)
    {
        cout << "error";
    }
    else
    {
        while(!datos.eof())
        {
            datos.get(valor);
            if(valor == 'I' && datos.peek() == 'D')
            {
                 cout << "I can read" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I´m trying to do this with C++, which is the correct way to do it? I´ve tried some ways, but i dont know how to read from one point to another, by this i mean read from the double comas the ID and finish on the other double comas.
Thanks in advance

Comment: ` while(!datos.eof())` <== https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce a integer state variable that describes what part of file you're in. Then interpret every character in accordance with that. For example, initially it's 0. Once you encounter a ", it becomes 1 - that means you're reading a name. If state is 1, and a character is not a "", you accumulate characters in some string variable. Once you encounter a quote character and state is 1, that means the name is over. And so on.

If this is not homework, Google for a C++ JSON parser. This is a stock problem, solved a thousand times already.

Also, please don't edit the answer - place a comment instead.